# when i use react router dom v6 display blank page without erreurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom v6 to switch between pages and it is rendering a blank page , navbar is not showing bit when i remove react-router-dom my page display also navbar is not showing
my page convert to blank page when add three react router dom in App.js

**index.js :**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />  
  </BrowserRouter> ,
  document.getElementById('root') 
);
```

App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import Accueil from './Components/Accueil';
import Avantages from './Components/Avantages';
import Fonctionnalite from './Components/Fonctionnalite';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import { Routes , Route } from 'react-router-dom' ;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Accueil/>} />
          <Route path="fonctionnalite" element={<Fonctionnalite/>} />
          <Route path="/avantages" element={<Avantages/>} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors? I don't see any overt issues with the shared code. If you remove `Navbar` do the routes then render? Can you manually navigate to each route? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: Yes , no errors ... when i remove navbar nothing change

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Comment: Ok but how i do this ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/project1-l5j0gg

Comment: There are errors, at least in the sandbox you linked. The `Navbar` component is rendering `Link` components with missing `to` props. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/project1-forked-gj02co?file=/src/Components/Navbar.js) fork. I've only commented out the links with missing `to` props since I can't guess what they should link to.